# dynamic loading content to QtextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing QT application in C++.

I have big .txt file (over 150k lines). I am loading the content to `QVector<QString>` like so:

```
QString line = "";
QVector<QString> content;
while (!in.atEnd()) {
        line = in.readLine();
        content.append(line);
    }
```

This is fast enough. The problem starts when I try to display the content in QtextEdit.

Before displaying I have to do some editing/operations. Then goes

```
for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
    ui->textEdit->append(content[i]);
}
```

It takes more than 100 seconds to show whole text and its to much (measured with QElapsedTimer).

So I want to ask, is there any easy way to load more content as the user scrolls down in QtextEdit?
For Example I will display 5000 lines, and when user scrolled to ~3/4, next 5000 lines is displayed and so on.

I am using vertical scroller build-in to QtextEdit.

Comment: I would try setting the entire text via `setText` instead of a line-by-line approach. The same goes for building a QString. Convert a stream to a single QString instead of a vector of QString. Line-by-line operations are much more expensive.

Comment: @IvanFateev loading from file to vector is fine. file.readAll() was quicker, but reading line by line is also fast enough and easier for me, as I have to perform operations on every line before printing.

Comment: @Marcineroo What Ivan tries to express is that instead of using content.appent() for every line, you might want to use a single QTextStream that you fill up. You can then also append the contents of the stream to the textEdit in a single call.

Comment: Okay, so what's the slowest part of your code? Does it work okay after you loaded all of the lines into the QTextEdit?

Comment: @IvanFateev slowest part is printing/displaying the content in QTextEdit.

Comment: Then replacing multiple calls of textEdit->append to textEdit->setText should dramatically improve the speed. Also if you don't have any formatting in the text setPlainText should be even faster.

Comment: When you fill you vector, you can also send a signal and catch with your `textEdit` every signal to append text